# TypeScript, best practices for multicomparison sorting in terms of readability

Tags: typescript, sorting

I have the following sorting function:

```
  orderForReports = (a: KeyValue<number, ProjectReport>, b: KeyValue<number, ProjectReport>): number => {
    return a.value.project.order.customer.name.toLowerCase() > b.value.project.order.customer.name.toLowerCase() ? 1 :
      b.value.project.order.customer.name.toLowerCase() > a.value.project.order.customer.name.toLowerCase() ? -1 :
        a.value.project.order.name.toLowerCase() > b.value.project.order.name.toLowerCase() ? 1 :
          b.value.project.order.name.toLowerCase() > a.value.project.order.name.toLowerCase() ? -1 :
            a.value.project.name.toLowerCase() > b.value.project.name.toLowerCase() ? 1 :
              b.value.project.name.toLowerCase() > a.value.project.name.toLowerCase() ? -1 : 0;
  };
```

First i order by `customer.name`. If `customer.name` is equal i sort by `order.name`. If `order.name` is equal i finally sort by `project.name`. So i have up to 3 levels of comparisons.

The code is all working and probably as efficient as it can get, but as you see theres a problem with readability. I wonder, are there any best practices for multicomparison sorting in TypeScript? Is there any other way to sort which is more readable and easier to understand?

Comment: Tip #1 - if you have multiple nested conditional operators - refactor to `if/else`. Tip #2 - don't use conditional operators at all.

Comment: If this code works, and you wrote it yourself, and you are willing to get advice on all aspects of the code, you may be better off posting this on [codereview.se], but I suggest reading their help center regarding what's on-topic first.

Comment: naming your comparisons is often a good habit when dealing with lots of conditions in the same place:  `const projectNameComesBefore = project.name < otherProject.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In almost all case "readability" and "conditional operator" are at odds. There are some instances where a conditional operator is shorter and easier to process for somebody looking at the source code but in the vast majority of cases an `if` statement is better. So, the *first* bit of refactoring is to turn this into a normal `if` statements:

```ts
orderForReports = (a: KeyValue <number, ProjectReport>, b: KeyValue <number, ProjectReport>): number => {
  if (a.value.project.order.customer.name.toLowerCase() > b.value.project.order.customer.name.toLowerCase())
    return 1;

  if (b.value.project.order.customer.name.toLowerCase() > a.value.project.order.customer.name.toLowerCase())
    return -1;

  if (a.value.project.order.name.toLowerCase() > b.value.project.order.name.toLowerCase())
    return 1;

  if (b.value.project.order.name.toLowerCase() > a.value.project.order.name.toLowerCase())
    return -1

  if (a.value.project.name.toLowerCase() > b.value.project.name.toLowerCase())
    return 1;

  if (b.value.project.name.toLowerCase() > a.value.project.name.toLowerCase())
    return -1;

  return 0;
};
```

We don't need the `else` parts, since each body of an `if` is just a single `return`, so the code won't continue down. We can drop the `{` and `}` around the body, since it's a single line anyway. It does make it easier to read rather than half the lines just being a closing bracket.

Still, this now highlights another issue - there is two comparison each time - one for `a > b` the other for `b > a`. And there is all those `toLowerCase()` calls that make the lines way longer and thus harder to read. Instead, you can use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) which has the benefits:

- It returns `-1`, `0`, or `1`, so you don't have to call this twice
- You can specify case insensitive comparison, instead of adding `.toLowerCase()` twice per line

So, if we just use use that, we can make the code shorter. We can also add the [extract variable](https://refactoring.guru/extract-variable) refactor to make it even easier to read:

```ts
orderForReports = (a: KeyValue <number, ProjectReport>, b: KeyValue <number, ProjectReport>): number => {
  const comparisonOptions = {sensitivity: "accent"};

  const customerNameOrder = a.value.project.order.customer.name
    .localeCompare         (b.value.project.order.customer.name, undefined, comparisonOptions);

  if (customerNameOrder !== 0)
    return customerNameOrder;

  const orderNameOrder = a.value.project.order.name
    .localeCompare      (b.value.project.order.name, undefined, comparisonOptions);

  if (orderNameOrder !== 0)
    return orderNameOrder;

  const projectNameOrder = a.value.project.name
    .localeCompare        (b.value.project.name, undefined, comparisonOptions);

  if (projectNameOrder !== 0)
    return projectNameOrder;

  return 0;
};
```

Now, there is only 3 cases, rather than 6. We've extracted each comparison to a variable and the variable name tells us *what* is being compared. The code is self-documenting, so it reads much easier than scanning the *entire* expression to figure out what's being compared. An absolutely trivial formatting like padding with whitespace allows us to verify that the comparison is correct *at a glance*, since the two expressions are right next to each other. If somebody makes a mistake and writes

```js
const orderNameOrder = a.value.project.order.name
  .localeCompare      (b.value.project.name, undefined, comparisonOptions);
```

it is going to be immediately apparent there is something wrong.

Comment: I don't think JS should have a Turkey Test problem, since [`String.prototype.toLowerCase()`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.tolowercase) and the like are required to use "locale-insensitive case mappings in the Unicode Character Database".  So `"I".toLowerCase()` should  always be `"i"` and never `"ı"`, even when your system locale is Turkish.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks, i could think of some more slight improvements. The if-statements can be simplified, for example `if (customerNameOrder!== 0)` could just be `if (customerNameOrder)`, because 0 is falsy. Furthermore, the last if-statement is not necessary, because if the check is false(`projectNameOrder` is 0) which i would return afterwards anyways. So i can just return `projectNameOrder` without any check at the end. Could even make it a one liner, but naming the variable gives a clue about whats going on so its maybe better to keep 2 lines.

Comment: That being said, the way you did it might be considered more readable than what i just suggested. I´m not sure.

Comment: @jcalz wow, OK, I learned something new today. I was always under the impression that `toLowerCase()` was using the current locale. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: @M.Dietz yes, there *are* further alterations you can make, like `if (customerNameOrder)` for example. However, I'd consider this mostly cosmetic and down to preference. Feel free to adjust more, my point was to go from nested conditional expressions to something anybody can look and understand without getting cross eyed in the process.

Answer (score 2):

Readability is subjective, but one way to possibly imagine improving things is to make some helper functions/classes/etc that turn functions that examine pieces of an object into functions that compare objects, and which can compose multiple of these to form a single comparison function.  The implementation of these helper functions might not be as readable, but they can be stored in a library somewhere.  The goal is to make the use of such functions readable.

Here's an example.  Imagine I have a `Person` interface and an array of instances of this interface:

```
interface Person {
    surname: string;
    givenName: string;
}

const people: Person[] = [
    { givenName: "John", surname: "Smith" },
    { givenName: "Jane", surname: "Smith" },
    { givenName: "June", surname: "Smith" },
    { givenName: "John", surname: "Doe" },
    { givenName: "Jane", surname: "Doe" },
    { givenName: "June", surname: "Doe" },
]
console.log(people.map(p => p.givenName + " " + p.surname).join(", "));
// John Smith, Jane Smith, June Smith, John Doe, Jane Doe, June Doe
```

I'd like to sort by surname first and then given name, both in a case-insensitive (and locale-insensitive) way.  Wouldn't it be nice if I could write this?

```
people.sort(compareOn(p => p.surname.toLowerCase(), p => p.givenName.toLowerCase()));

console.log(people.map(p => p.givenName + " " + p.surname).join(", "));
// Jane Doe, John Doe, June Doe, Jane Smith, John Smith, June Smith
```

And maybe I'd even like to sort by surname in ascending order and then given name in *descending* order (who knows why I'd want to do that with names; maybe I'm not completely sane).  Maybe I would be able to do modify the code like this:

```
people.sort(compareOn(
    p => p.surname.toLowerCase(),
    { fn: p => p.givenName.toLowerCase(), dir: "desc" }
));

console.log(people.map(p => p.givenName + " " + p.surname).join(", "));
// June Doe, John Doe, Jane Doe, June Smith, John Smith, Jane Smith
```

---

Well, we can do both of those with a suitable implementation of `compareOn()`.  Here's a possibility:

```
type ToOrderable<T> = ((x: T) => string | number | boolean) | {
    fn: ((x: T) => string | number | boolean);
    dir: "asc" | "desc"
}

const compareOn =
    <T>(...toOrderables: Array<ToOrderable<T>>): (x: T, y: T) => number =>
        toOrderables.map(
            o => (x: T, y: T) => {
                const [sgn, f] = "fn" in o ? [o.dir === "desc" ? -1 : 1, o.fn] : [1, o];
                const fx = f(x);
                const fy = f(y);
                return sgn * (fx < fy ? -1 : fy < fx ? 1 : 0);
            }
        ).reduce(
            (a, f) => (x: T, y: T) => a(x, y) || f(x, y)
        );
```

`compareOn()` takes a variable number of `ToOrderable<T>` values for some type `T`.  A `ToOrderable<T>` is either a function that converts a `T` to `string | number | boolean` (which is something JavaScript can actually compare with `<`), *or* it's an object that contains a property `fn` of that type as well as a `dir` property of either `"asc"` or `"desc"`.

Its implementation isn't super important here; you could write it however you want as long as it works.  What I've done is taken the `toOrderables` array, `map`ped each element to a comparison function that returns `-1 | 0 | 1`, and then `reduce`s those to a single function.  The reduction step `a(x, y) || f(x, y)` is just saying "take the existing comparison function `a` and compare `a(x, y)`.  If it's `-1` or `1`, that's the answer.  Otherwise consult the next function `f` and return `f(x, y)`.

---

Anyway, hope that gives another idea for how to proceed.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg9geQE4BMJIIYCMA2EA8MAfFALxQAUFAHgFywCUZJAzsEgJYB2A5lAD5QuAVwC2WdAKhY4cPBi5NBAbwBQUDVABmXelTqNmUNp15SR4yYJlyIChgG51mlByT0ARBhYBjD1I80Xw9VAF9VVR84LjYoKNEwDCQIBC4yZw1CIgoAOjzgRFR0bDwWegBBJEwQQkK0TFwCYiIGPQMYABooEHoYJlISCwkkZgzNDQLkepKIFhzRDDAKMfHxuCMaXq6ewwGoNVXD1aiY4CgAbRYeLi6tAF0yKA8df24odYB+C7gc1xHSAFPIJ+KBfAC0AEYoPQIV0fjoHvRzrD3ncnEcMXForEtNRHloaI4VpiNCccSB8RQQESSYdksBhEg0lc0gAqSi4qD4bQU8FQ+haCnczlfflQAAMNNp4QxDByyRQwh8EGWtMoGFu-RIm1g216WqgGBo2yUggJ1BNxI0NIi3GA6C0GGVUAACugWNF9mMWIyuBhRBB6CZuDx0ZoeBwAG4QLgAOX9geM7BDTnCkWxZ0gcDAeHobqQHq45we5HOY2UUAj0bjCc8ACk4AALLgeLo+pm1p4AZVEHGAjf8oQ65crUZj8YD9YUEFbxl9nY8Pb7A6gQ5HVfHC7rwi4M7b88n3d7-cHw-GFY3NcPHgbzdn7b914AInAZ6uz5oL2Or4mb9P7wev4vm+a7nqO1YTr+267gBHbPq+p6qHc6YxLYOQ4HAPAUFmOYQPMizYUYYA5JekFQAA1E8VGUcRD4JnKABWcDcBQs4eAwRIAPScVAt5pEu-ZdHW05QAJjZCTu0BiUJTZpMBQkifJvGSVAwERDheA5B6SDABQ8SJMkqSEXstGATkBQADJwAA7ugADC3gqgwXRgERJHfpB5lwFZtlIA5LBORxTgoR6mkYVhGl4QsSyuSZ7kQQmFFUf4NFaYBjHMVwrFdOxXE8cJu6qa+MnNkVEASYVSkFVJx7ibxsmibVFU1cu6kQNmmnabp+lJCkWVjLFJCmXBeGWTZ9mORQzkjjo9CDVAxGkQmXk+RNAVTV0fyeMCg6qEFERkmh4XYe1uH4TFblLQGSX+ClC1pSNGUsWx+3ccplXFfVpVVYpn3QS1glffxTW8SJYkREAA)